# YAML Unmarshal map[string]struct

Tags: go, yaml

I am definitely not getting this. Here is a given yaml file

```
items:
  - item1:
      one: "some"
      two: "some string"
  - item2:
      one: "some"
      two: "some string"
```

And a config:

```golang
type Item struct {
    one string
    two string
}
type conf struct {
    Items map[string]Item
}

func (c *conf) getConfig(filename string) *conf {

    yamlFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("yamlFile.Get err   #%v ", err)
    }
    err = yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &c)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unmarshal: %v", err)
    }

    //c.Items = make(map[string]Items)
    return c
}
```

I am using `gopkg.in/yaml.v2`

With this error:

```
Unmarshal: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 6: cannot unmarshal !!seq into map[string]application.Item
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong here. I googled everywhere already. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to change your YAML to

```
  items:
      item1:
        one: "some"
        two: "some string"
      item2:
        one: "some"
        two: "some string"
```

Then, in your go code

```
type Config struct {
    Items map[string]Item
}

type Item struct {
    One string
    Two string
}
```

Then with

```
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", c.Items)
```

you will have

```
map[item1:{One:some Two:some string} item2:{One:some Two:some string}]
```

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple problems with your mapping:

- `Item` struct members are not exported. You have to export them:

```
type Item struct {
    One string `yaml:"one"`
    Two string `yaml:"two"`
}
```

- `Items` is an array of map of `Item`s

```
type conf struct {
    Items []map[string]Item `yaml:"items"`
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I should pay more attention to the structure and exported items! Just started learning GO